# Plain to postname permalinks not working

Tags: permalinks

I have recently managed (with help from this forum ), to upload the site www.gas-spring.com .

I had the permalink setting set to plain when making the pages etc... now I want to clean them up and change them to permalink setting post name. when changing them i can only open the homepage but any other links are not working.

I have found a simple workaround, setting the permalinks to custom with /index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/ . This cleans them up a little but still not the result I want.

Can you perhaps help me once more in solving this. So I just want to change permalinks to post name without errors off course.

Thanks in advance.

The webserver used is an Apache server, the .htaccess file is set to 644 and looks like ;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache Write mode is not enabled.
#>sudo a2enmod rewrite
[sudo] password:
Enabling module rewrite.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
systemctl restart apache2

It should be working after this.